# Dropdown menus falling behind page content

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

The Wordpress site that I maintain was updated a couple months ago, after which our dropdown menus stopped working properly.

www.grkroccenter.org

The menus are there and functioning, just not correctly. Sometimes you can reload a page and hover over a link that has a dropdown (such as "PROGRAMS" or "ABOUT US") and while the page is loading, you will briefly see the dropdown, but then the page loads and the content seems to fall on top of the dropdown menu.

I've tried various z-index solutions, and I am a graphic designer, NOT a programmer or Wrodpress expert. I only help maintain this site; I didn't create it, and YES, I know how messy the code is.

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more info, just ask. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like `display:none` is not getting overridden for the sub menus upon hover... The superfish.js file seems to set the visibility, but not undo the display:none set for the sub menu elements.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Ok, I read that thread... and I'm assuming I should post some CSS code here, but I have no idea what to post.

Comment: Can you please post your CSS code here?

Comment: I don't know what to post. What CSS do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The sub-menu is set to display: none which means it will never be visible unless overridden. You need something like this:

```
.menu-item:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything like that in my code in the stylesheet... I tried posting the code but the character limit here is too restrictive and it won't let me post the necessary menu coding.

My menu code looks something like this (see next comment):

Comment: `}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
    background:     #c0bdb0;
 color: #000;
 outline:  0;
}

.sf-menu li:hover ul,
.sf-menu li.sfHover ul {
 top:32px; /* overriding essential styles */
}
.sf-menu ul ul {
    margin-top:0;
}
.sf-menu ul a {
    background:#a4a196;
 color: #000;
 border-bottom:none;
}
.sf-menu ul a:hover {
     background:#c0bdb0;
  color: #000;
}

.sf-js-enabled ul li ul {
 margin-left: auto !important;
}

.sf-menu ul li ul {
 margin-left:110px;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to get my code to show up all nice and organized like it is in the style sheet. I tried hard returns but that didn't work.